# Binary Search Tree Problem with Insert Function

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Hello i am new to c++ and learning about binary search trees.
I am trying to implement a simple binary search tree where i can store "KeyCodePair" object(which has string and integer) and doing some operations on tree like search and insert. Seems like there are some problems with my logic thats why first Insert function is working but second is not working(calling them from Main) I guess there is problem with the way i implemented "root" where should i write it

This is Tree.cpp:

```
#include "Tree.h";
#include "KeyCodePair.h";
Tree::Tree() {
    treeNode* root = NULL;
}
Tree::treeNode* Tree::getNewNode(KeyCodePair data) {

    treeNode* newNode = new treeNode();
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;
}
   Tree::treeNode* Tree::Insert(KeyCodePair data) {
    if (root == NULL) { 
        root = getNewNode(data);
    }
    else if (data.getCode() <= root->data.getCode()) {
        root->left = Insert(data);
    }
    else {
        root->right = Insert(data);
    }
    return root;
}
bool Tree::Search(KeyCodePair data) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        return false;
    }
    else if (root->data.getCode() == data.getCode()) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (data.getCode() <= root->data.getCode()) {
        return Search(data);
    }
    else {
        return Search(data);
    }
}
```

Tree.h:

```
#ifndef TREE_H
#define TREE_H
#include "KeyCodePair.h"
class Tree {
private:
     struct treeNode {
        KeyCodePair data;
        treeNode* left;
        treeNode* right;
    } ;
     treeNode* root;
public:
    treeNode* Insert( KeyCodePair data);
    bool Search(KeyCodePair data);
    treeNode* getNewNode(KeyCodePair data);
    Tree();
};
#endif
```

KeyCodePair.cpp

```
#include "KeyCodePair.h"
KeyCodePair::KeyCodePair(string keyparam, int codeparam) {
    key = keyparam;
    code = codeparam;
}
KeyCodePair::KeyCodePair() {

}
string KeyCodePair::getKey() {
    return key;

}
int KeyCodePair::getCode() {
    return code;
}
```

KeyCodePair.h

```
#ifndef KEYCODEPAIR_H
#define KEYCODEPAIR_H
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class KeyCodePair {
private:
    string key;
    int code;
public:
    KeyCodePair();
    KeyCodePair(string key, int code);
    string getKey();
    int getCode();

};

#endif
```

And Finally this is the main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Tree.h"
#include "KeyCodePair.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Tree tree =  Tree();
    KeyCodePair testPair =  KeyCodePair("teststring1",10);
    KeyCodePair qwePair = KeyCodePair("teststring2", 20);
    cout << tree.Insert(testPair) << endl;
    cout << tree.Insert(qwePair) << endl; // problem on second insert

    if (tree.Search(testPair) == true) cout << "Found\n";
    else cout << "Not Found\n";
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++ is worth the effort, good thing you're learning it! The best suggestion I have is that you get used to run things in debug mode if you're using pointers.Your problem would not be a problem if you did.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at your insert function:

```
Tree::treeNode* Tree::Insert(KeyCodePair data) {
    if (root == NULL) { 
        root = getNewNode(data);
    }
    else if (data.getCode() <= root->data.getCode()) {
        root->left = Insert(data);
    }
    else {
        root->right = Insert(data);
    }
    return root;
}
```

What you do here is you take in the data to be inserted, and you look at the root. If there is no root, you add a new node containing the data and assign that to the root (which is why your first insert works). However, once there is a root, you then figure out if the new node should be placed to the left or right of the root, and then recursively call Insert() with the same data. This next call to Insert will do nothing different, and look at the same root of the tree over and over to most likely produce an infinite loop.

What you have to do is using your data, first traverse all the way down the tree to the position at which you want to insert your node, then insert it and assign the pointers. Some code for this might look like so:

```
Tree::Insert(KeyCodePair data) {
    // currPos will end up being the position where we want to insert
    Tree::treeNode* currPos = root;
    while (currPos != NULL) {
        if (data.getCode() <= currPos->data.getCode())
            currPos = currPos->left;
        else if (data.getCode() > currPos->data.getCode())
            currPos = currPos->right;
    }

    // Insert at currPos and reassign the left or right pointer of 
    // the parent
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer.What about the search function

Comment: @l0veisreal It would be very similar to Insert. You will traverse down the tree starting at the root, checking the code at each node. If they are equal, you found it and can return that node. If the code your searching for is less than that of the current node, move down the tree to the left to the next node and continue searching. If it is greater, move down the tree to the right and continue searching.

Comment: actually i just realized i forgot to add -> left and ->right near after root:D lol thansk

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your insert only considers the root node. You need to traverse down the tree to the point where you do the insert:

```
class Tree {
   ...
public:
    treeNode* Insert(KeyCodePair data);
    ...
};
```

Step 1: Change your interface

```
class Tree {
   ...
    // The insert that does the work
    // We pass in the current position in the tree.
    treeNode* Insert(treeNode* node, KeyCodePair data);
public:

    // The public interface that accepts the data and calls the internal Insert
    void Insert(KeyCodePair data);
    ...
};
```

Step 2: Use the public Insert to call the internal Insert.

```
void Tree::Insert(KeyCodePair data) {
    // Use the internal Insert() passing the root as the starting point.
    // If a new value is needed it will be returned otherwise the original
    // value is returned.
    root = Insert(root, data);
}
```

Step 3: Modify the OP Insert into an Internal Insert.

```
Tree::treeNode* Tree::Insert(treeNode* node, KeyCodePair data) {
    if (node == NULL) { 
        // If we have reached the tip of the tree then
        // return the new node so it can be inserted.
        return getNewNode(data);
    }

    // Otherwise we have a node so we need to find the node
    // were the data will be inserted.
    // so move to the next level. Assign the result as the next
    // level could be null.
    if (data.getCode() <= root->data.getCode()) {
        node->left  = Insert(node->left,  data);
    }
    else {
        node->right = Insert(node->right, data);
    }

    // Return this node
    // So it stays in the chain.
    return node;
}
```